# Qode slider pause/stop when on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hi Guys just looking for some help here been stuck on this quiet awhile. So what I want Is just the first image from the slide when the website is displayed in any screen less than 800px . I am using the bridge theme on WordPress and the Qode plugin for the slider. I tried searching every where with no luck.

here is the link to the js file

https://jsfiddle.net/zgh9cyww

and here is the code i have in my header

```
$j(window).resize(function() {
    if( $j(this).width() <= 800 ) {
        console.log("in ");
    $j(this).carousel({
        interval: 0,
        pause: true
    }); 
    }else{
        console.log("out ");
        $j(this).carousel({
            interval: 6000,
            pause: true
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: `$j(this)` is `$j(window)` inside your `resize`. Is your carousel attached to the window somehow? I doubt it. You need to set it to the element where your `carousel` is displayed...

Comment: @dingo_d hey thanks for the reply. So if i set it to the div that holds the carousel. Could you give me a quick example if you have the time. Thanks.

Comment: @C0dekid hey here you go https://jsfiddle.net/zgh9cyww/#&togetherjs=gKThDpl0UF

Comment: Why don't you create a fiddle with your code from google drive? So that we can see the issue. Basically this `$j(this).carousel({` should be `$j('.your-carousel-element').carousel({`

Comment: @dingo_d I just created the fiddle hope i done it right its my first time using it.